# hokuyo subscriber callback delay?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, callback, hokuyo, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am trying to subscribe to a laser scan of the hokuyo_node. (UTM-30LX)
I have checked that the rostopic(/scan) satisfied 40Hz.
$rostopic hz /scan

However, msg(/scan) callback is not satisfied 40Hz. (0.025sec)
Can I subscribe a rostopic(/scan) with 40Hz?

```
[ INFO] [1556028820.890011693]: 231]Laser 1.112000 0.117000 0.486000
[ INFO] [1556028820.890147465]: 232]Laser 1.113000 0.119000 0.485000
[ INFO] [1556028820.933906513]: 233]Laser 1.118000 0.120000 0.488000
[ INFO] [1556028820.934033465]: 234]Laser 1.114000 0.128000 0.486000
[ INFO] [1556028820.977954391]: 235]Laser 1.112000 0.109000 0.488000
[ INFO] [1556028820.978087813]: 236]Laser 1.112000 0.117000 0.493000
[ INFO] [1556028821.021961768]: 237]Laser 1.113000 0.110000 0.492000
[ INFO] [1556028821.027527888]: 238]Laser 1.116000 0.116000 0.487000
[ INFO] [1556028821.070109309]: 239]Laser 1.113000 0.128000 0.486000
```

I using a source code below.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
void laserCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr & scan)
{
    ROS_INFO("%d]Laser %f %f %f", scan->header.seq, scan->ranges[0], scan->ranges[360], scan->ranges[719]);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "laser_scan");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::Subscriber scan_sub = nh.subscribe("/scan", 1000, laserCallback);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321688/hokuyo-subscriber-callback-delay??/) by [Gspark](https://answers.ros.org/users/28537/gspark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-23**:
Please do not post screenshots of terminals, there is no need. It's all text, so copy-paste the console text into your question. Then use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) to properly format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm slightly confused by your statements, but if you mean that `rostopic hz ..` prints that the topic is publishing at 40 Hz but your callback doesn't appear to be receiving messages at 40 Hz, then you might want to look into setting the `tcpNoDelay` transport hint ([docs](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Transport_Hints)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gspark](https://answers.ros.org/users/28537/gspark/) on 2019-04-23**:
@gvdhoorn Correct! I prints that the topic is publishing at 40 Hz but callback didn't appear to be receiving messages at 40 Hz. It was solved with your advice. thank you.

```
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/scan", 1000, laserCallback, ros::TransportHints().tcpNoDelay());
```

ps. How I select your comment for best answer?